# Pure js code works in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript

The code below works fine in Firefox, in Chrome it behaves quite strage. For short loops(below several hundreds) it works, but for large it never ends. Sometimes it can break from that infinite loop and complete.

This could be fixed by replacing "delete _scope.context" with _scope.context=undefined

Can someone elaborate what is going on here?

```js
(function() {
  var _module = function() {
    const _scope = function() {
      var a = 0,
        block = 0;
      var suspend = function() {
        var context = {};
        context.a = a;
        context.block = block;
        context.resume = function() {
          _scope.context = context;
          return _scope();
        }
        _scope.context = context;
        return context;
      }
      var awake = function() {
        context = _scope.context;
        delete _scope.context;
        //_scope.context = undefined;
        a = context.a;
        block = context.block;
      }
      if (_scope.context !== undefined) {
        awake();
      }
      while (true) {
        switch (block) {
          case 0:
            block = 1;
            return suspend();
          case 1:
            block = 0;
            if (a++ > 10000) {
              return;
            }
            continue;
        }
      }
    }
    return _scope();
  }

  var runMod = function() {
    var susp = _module();
    var nSteps = 0;
    while (susp) {
      susp = susp.resume();
      if (!(++nSteps % 1000)) {
        console.log(nSteps, susp);
      }
      if (nSteps > 100000) {
        console.log('aborted')
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log('complete', nSteps);
  }

  runMod();
})()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/daborkpw/

Comment: Seems to work fine for me? Maybe you're still using an older version of Chrome.

Comment: I am also on a not-up-to-date chrome (74) and I see the difference between the two

Comment: To clarify, I added sane check and program stops after abnormal amount of steps. If you see "aborted" in console, that means something went wrong

Comment: I am on Chrome 74.0.3729.157, up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Chrome, will be fixed in 75
The fix https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/1617251/6/src/runtime/runtime-object.cc#84